# Unable to configure RustDT correctly, Windows

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rust

I am currently trying to gett the RustDT-plugin to run correctly in Eclipse for Windows. After working through the guides and tutorials for 2 hours I am still not able to set it up correctly.

I think that every required component (like Racer) is installed correctly, because I am able to create a project without any problems.

I wrote a "hello world", but it is either throwing errors or running through without errors, but not showing the string on the console.

I created a project called "my_project".
The first thing I notice is, that the building creates an .exe with a suffix that looks like a hashed value. While the guides and the standard configuration showed that there should be a "my_project.exe", I get a "my_project-e8a2b45078d7e959.exe".

This is where I first got an error message stating that the "my_project.exe" is not existing. No problem. Setting that name in the run configurations solves it. But now I get following message:

```
running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured
```

Here it looks to me that it is still not working properly, because I don't get the "Hello, world"-message. I totally don't know what I'm doing wrong. I hope one of you guys can point out my mistake.

I would also appreciate if someone describes what he/she did regarding run/build configurations for the first project.

Comment: This is the output of a test executable, not the project's main binary.

Comment: Could it be you are building a library rather than an executable?

Comment: But what exactly does that mean? Is the test executable overwriting my projects output or don't I get any project output at all?
I tried to find a way to set my main.rs to set as the file to run (like in Java), but I didn't find anything like that.

Comment: @Neikos I deleted the lib.rs, which was created automatically. In the docs I learned that you use a lib.rs if you want to create a library, otherwise a main.rs. Anything else was not changed and exactly like the values from the docs.

Comment: If a lib.rs was generated then it means that it probably created a config file for a library. I have no experience with eclipse and rust, but can you try to create a new project and see if you can change that somewhere?

Comment: The only changeable setting was a checkbox `Use 'cargo init' to create project`. Unselecting it did not create the lib.rs, but it automatically created a main.rs. But I still get the message from above. I executed the .exe, which was created during the build, with the Windows command prompt, in the hope to see the "hello world" there. Even there I got that message from above.

Comment: I played arount with the build command, changing it from `${CARGO_TOOL_PATH} test --no-run` to `cargo build` or `cargo run`, but without any difference. But each new build creates a new run configuration with `${CARGO_TOOL_PATH} test --no-run` if there is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it somehow, even if I don't exactly know how (and why) it got solved.

Under build targets in the project explorer I configured my build target `build` (right-click on `build` -> `Configure target...`).

There I disabled the option `Enable for workspace build`, unchecked `Use default value` in the section `Build Command`, and changed the value in the text area to `cargo build`.

I executed the main-method by right-clicking on my build target `build`, then `Run` and finally choosing the exe (suddenly without the suffix) that should be run.

I got that idea by reading in the [github-forum of RustDT](https://github.com/RustDT/RustDT/issues/67). So I tried it so see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple. Rust Eclipse Tool, by default, wants to build a library which is "run" by its unit tests. Fix is

1. Go to run configurations.
2. Disable Checkbox Use Build Target settings.
3. Enter String “${CARGO_TOOL_PATH} build” in Text box below.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a new external configuration to execute
`cargo run` in project location. Also is important to uncheck "build before run" in External tool config.

I have wrote details tutorial here: https://medium.com/@leonid.vygovsky/configure-rustdt-for-rust-learners